# Nested VLookup returning 1 value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need to be able to extract a specific date and shifts `Count` (Expr1003 column). I'm thinking I need to use a `Vlookup` inside a `vlookup` but I'm pretty sure this is not right.

```
Expr1001    shift   Expr1003
17-Sep-17   01      12128
17-Sep-17   03      31721
18-Sep-17   01      28445
18-Sep-17   02      5856
18-Sep-17   03      34544
19-Sep-17   01      16499
19-Sep-17   02      8733
19-Sep-17   03      41136
```

I don't know why I can't figure this out. I've tried just going with a straight nested `VLOOKUP` inside of a `VLOOKUP` but what I need is for the inner `VLOOKUP` to return a table array.

Edit: Okay I don't think I clearly communicated my issue.

I have an empty array I need to fill out
[image: Table to fill out]
I want to just input formulas in that part of the chart that is empty to be able to call out shift volumes.

Comment: countifs function allows you to count meeting multiple conditions

Comment: It's the grey output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using a single VLOOKUP with a concatenated key.

Assuming your columns are 
A (Day Names), 
B (Dates),
C (NPS Daily Total)
and Rows are 1 2 3 such that "Sunday" is cell A3, 
and the grey area starts at G1 (G1 = "Expr1001") with H2 = "01",
you would do the following:

1. create a new column to the left of G (pushing G to H).
2. in column G concatenate H and I so that G2 becomes:

   =H2&I2

This then becomes your key for the lookup.

Put in cell D3 the following (assumes your data goes down to row 200):

```
=VLOOKUP($B3&"01",$G2:$J$200,3, False)
```

Clearly, you would be better off adding a row that stores the string at the top of your table and use that to store the shift instead of hardcoding in the formula. Assuming it is row 1, then D3 would be

```
= VLOOKUP($B3&D$1,$G2:$J$200,3, False)
```

And then you can copy that down and across.

And that should give you what you need. It assumes both your date ranges are actually date ranges and therefore equivalent under the hood. I note they are displayed differently here, but it is the underlying date value that matters.